# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: [server] failed to respond error after installing Kaspersky

Tags: jmeter, postman, kaspersky

We have installed Kaspersky anti-virus a few days ago, and when we ran our old Jmeter tests, it raises the exception below.

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: target server failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ...
```

When we ran some sample requests in Postman, it also raised errors like socket hang-up or connection reset, but after adding Postman to Kaspersky's exception list, the application executed the tests normally.

We tried adding the jmeter.bat and ApacheJmeter.jar file to the exception list, but Jmeter still raised the NoHttpResponseException even with the exact same request we ran with Postman (we used the test-script recording).

Are we missing more files to be added to the exception list?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding java.exe and javaw.exe to the exception list